# Ending Numpy Calculation Early

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

Given two large arrays,

```
A = np.random.randint(10,size=(10000,2))
B = np.random.randint(10,size=(10000,2))
```

I would like to determine if any of the vectors have a cross product of zero. We could do

```
C = np.cross(A[:,None,:],B[None,:,:])
```

and then check if C contains a 0 or not.

```
not C.all()
```

However, this process requires calculating all the cross products which can be time consuming. Instead, I would prefer to let numpy perform the cross product, but IF a zero is reached at any point, then simply cut the whole operation and end early. Does numpy have such an "early termination" operation that will cut numpy operations early if they reach a condition? Something like,

```
np.allfunc()
np.anyfunc()
```

The example above is such a case where A and B have an extremely high likelihood of having a zero cross product at some point (in fact is very likely to occur near the start), so much so, that performing a python-for-loop (yuck!) is much faster than using numpy's highly optimized code.

In general, what is the fastest way to determine if A and B have a zero cross product?

Comment: I'm not aware of any early termination method, though one may exist. To me, it seems like the only option may be to write your own looping method that terminates when the condition is met. This may be sped up using numba, if speed is really important.

Comment: Numpy doesn't provide short-circuit evaluation. This is a consequence of the design decision to vectorize operations anywhere possible. A potential solution is to write a generator which yields cross products and pass that generator to the stdlib `not all()`.

Comment: I realized we could just do `bool(len(np.intersect1d(A[..., 0] / A[..., 1], B[..., 0] / B[..., 1])))`. It would be fast enough to make early termination unnecessary. But it might give inaccurate results due to rounding errors. I wonder if there's a better way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does numpy have such an "early termination" operation that will cut numpy operations early if they reach a condition?

**Put it simply, no, Numpy does not.**
In practice, this is a bit more complex than that.

---

In fact, the `allfunc` and `anyfunc` function you propose similar to `np.all` and `np.any`. Such function does some kind of early termination. Here is a proof on my machine:

```py
v = np.random.randint(0, 2, 200*1024*1024) > 0

# 2.74 ms ± 61.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit -n 10 v.all()

# 3.16 ms ± 46.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
v[0:v.size//16] = True
%timeit -n 10 v.all()

# 3.72 ms ± 77.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
v[0:v.size//8] = True
%timeit -n 10 v.all()

# 4.64 ms ± 80.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
v[0:v.size//4] = True
%timeit -n 10 v.all()

# 6.67 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
v[0:v.size//2] = True
%timeit -n 10 v.all()

# 10.5 ms ± 69.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
v[0:v.size] = True
%timeit -n 10 v.all()
```

The former is so fast that it cannot possibly iterate over the whole array since the memory throughput would reach 71 GiB/s while my RAM can only reach the theoretical maximum bandwidth of 47.7 GiB/s (about 40 GiB/s in practice). My CPU cache is far from being big enough to store a significant part of this array and the array takes 200 MiB in RAM so each boolean takes 1 byte in RAM. Strangely, the speed of `all` and `any` is quite disappointing in the first case since `v[2]` is `False` in practice. Numpy certainly perform the computation chunk by chunk and perform the early termination only after computing a chunk (if needed).

The problem with `any` and `all` is that they **require a boolean array** in parameter. Thus, the boolean array need to be **entirely computed first defeating the benefit of any early termination**.

---

Alternatively, Numpy provides [ufuncs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html) that are designed to operate on arrays in an element-by-element fashion. An example of ufunc is `np.ufunc.reduce`. They could be used to *compose algorithms* in such a way early termination would theoretically be possible. This solution would be significantly faster than usual non-ufunc operations when termination is possible pretty early. However, when the termination is only possible lately, ufuncs would be much slower than non-ufunc operations. In fact, ufuncs are (currently) fundamentally inefficient compared to non-ufunc operations. This is because ufuncs require an expensive (native) *function call* per item. This function call, applied on a scalar items, prevent several critical optimizations like the use of *SIMD instructions*. Still, ufuncs can often be faster than using pure-Python code element-by-element thanks to ["vectorization"](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/glossary.html#term-vectorization). The current way ufuncs can be composed is AFAIK not sufficient, in your use-case, to write an efficient code benefiting from early termination.

---

The standard way to do early termination in Numpy is to split the computation in many **chunks** (manually). This solution is generally fast because it is vectorized, often SIMD-friendly, and cache efficient (assuming chunks are small enough). The overhead of Numpy is small as long as chunks are big enough. Here is an example:

```py
def compute_by_chunk(A, B):
    chunkSize = 256
    for i in range(0, A.size, chunkSize):
        for j in range(0, B.size, chunkSize):
            C = np.cross(A[i:i+chunkSize,None,:], B[None,j:j+chunkSize,:])
            if not C.all():
                # print(f'Zero found in chunk ({i},{j})')
                return True
    return False
```

For your example of input, it takes 239 µs on my machine while the naive Numpy implementation takes 234 ms. This is about 1000 times faster in this case. With smaller chunks, like 32x32, the computation is even faster: 32.3 µs.

Actually, smaller chunks are better when there are a lot of zeros (since it takes time to compute the first chunk). 256x256 should be relatively good on most machines (rather cache friendly, memory efficient and with low Numpy overhead).

---

A more simpler solution (which is also generally faster) is to use modules/tools, like **Cython or Numba**, compiling your code so loops can be fast thanks to compilation to native functions. However, with this solution, you need to reimplement the cross product yourself. Indeed, Numba does not support it yet and Cython will not be faster (than a pure-Python code using Numpy) if you just call Numpy functions in loops.

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed discussion. I normally avoid loops as much as I can in my array manipulations, but I like the compute_by_chunk(), which seems to retain most of vectorized speed.

Answer (score 0):

This question has already accepted the answer, but I would like to post my answer here for those who googled zero cross product and landed on this question.

I recommend a more mathematical approach.

The cross product of 2D vectors `a` and `b` is zero when `a0*b1 = a1*b0`.
This can be transformed into `a0/a1 = b0/b1`.
Therefore, it can be implemented as follows.

```py
np.any(np.isin(A[..., 0] / A[..., 1], B[..., 0] / B[..., 1]))
```

In order for this to work, we must first take care of the zero division issue.

- For `n/0` case, we can fill it with `np.inf`. Note that in numpy, [np.inf == np.inf](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf).
- For `0/0` case, we can return `True` immediately. Since `np.cross([(0,0)], [(n,n)]) == [0]`.

```py
import numpy as np


def has_zero_vector(a):
    """Return True if a contains (0, 0)."""
    return not np.all(np.logical_or(a[..., 0], a[..., 1]))


def safe_divide(a, b):
    """Compute a / b. Where b is 0, fill in np.inf."""
    out = np.full(len(a), dtype=np.float64, fill_value=np.inf)
    np.divide(a, b, out=out, where=b != 0)
    return out


def has_zero_cross_product(a, b):
    # Since 0/0 is messy, returns True immediately if there is one.
    if has_zero_vector(a) or has_zero_vector(b):
        return True

    ar = safe_divide(a[..., 0], a[..., 1])
    br = safe_divide(b[..., 0], b[..., 1])
    return np.any(np.isin(ar, br))


A = np.random.randint(10,size=(10000,2))
B = np.random.randint(10,size=(10000,2))
has_zero_cross_product(A, B)
```

It does not attempt early termination (except for `0/0`), but is 20000 times faster than the OP's code and 20 times faster than the Jérôme's chunked computation.
The reason it is so fast is mainly because your inputs are not varied and have many duplicates. This makes it easy to compute the `np.isin`.

Note that this function is also compatible with chunked computation.
However, because the computation is too small, the overhead is likely greater than the benefit of early termination and may make little or no difference.

Another perspective, (not sure if this helps the OP, but) this function is still effective even if the probability of zero cross product is low.

For example, given the following inputs, the probability of the zero cross product existing is 50-50.

```py
np.random.seed(0)
A = np.random.randint(0, 40000, size=(10000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 40000, size=(10000, 2))
has_zero_cross_product(A, B)
# False

np.random.seed(1)
A = np.random.randint(0, 40000, size=(10000, 2))
B = np.random.randint(0, 40000, size=(10000, 2))
has_zero_cross_product(A, B)
# True
```

Even in this case, it is still 150 times faster than the OP's code and more than 100 times faster than the Jérôme's chunked computation.
Note that in this case, making this function chunked computation will only make it slower.

As a final supplement, if we are allowed to use [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/), the following optimizations can be made:

```py
import numba


@numba.njit(cache=True)
def has_intersect_sorted(a, b):
    """Determine if a and b have a common element."""
    # Both a and b must be sorted.
    # assert np.all(a[1:] >= a[:-1])
    # assert np.all(b[1:] >= b[:-1])
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
        # By modifying this if statement as below, it can also support float input arrays.
        # But, it may be inaccurate due to rounding errors.
        # if np.isclose(a[i], b[j], atol=0.0, rtol=1e-14):
        #     return True
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            return True

        if a[i] < b[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1

    return False


def has_zero_cross_product2(a, b):
    if has_zero_vector(a) or has_zero_vector(b):
        return True

    ar = safe_divide(a[..., 0], a[..., 1])
    br = safe_divide(b[..., 0], b[..., 1])
    ar.sort()  # Sorting is required.
    br.sort()
    return has_intersect_sorted(ar, br)
```

The main purpose of this optimization is not early termination, but to compute the intersection in O(n) (strictly speaking, O(n log n) is required for sorting).
Therefore, this makes it another 1.5 times faster in the 50-50 case, but makes little difference in the high probability case.

In summary, unless you almost always have a zero cross product at the very beginning of the input, you don't need early termination in your case.

Comment: While my question was intended to be more general and only work with np.cross() as an example where early termination might be desired, I do highly appreciate the code you have provide. This is a very helpful increase in speed on np.cross() checking.